# Name typescript Type for event handler?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, events

Refer [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-create-multilevel-dropdown-menu-react/) to implement detect click outside component.

```
    const [
        dropdown,
        setDropdown
    ] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const ref = useRef<HTMLLIElement>();

    useEffect(() => {
        const handler = (event: any) => {
            if (
                dropdown &&
            ref.current &&
            !ref.current.contains(event.target)
            ) {
                setDropdown(false);
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handler);
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', handler);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handler);
            document.removeEventListener('touchstart', handler);
        };
    }, [dropdown]);
```

What type is `event` ? I tried doing `ChangeEvent<HTMLLIElement>` but it said no function overload when used inside of the `.addEventListener()` function calls.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using VS Code, hover on the function (`.addEventListener`) and you will see something like this:

```
(method) Document.addEventListener<"mousedown">(type: "mousedown", listener: (this: Document, ev: MouseEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void (+1 overload)
```

so the type of `event` is `MouseEvent`:

```
const handler = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    // ...
};

document.addEventListener('mousedown', handler);
```

Just FYI: holding Ctrl and click the method will bring you to the type definition, you could check more details about that function there.

Comment: Yes @Jerryh001 , it might be  MouseEvent | TouchEvent